# Implementation of Cramer-Shoup encryption scheme failing with GNU's GMP Library

Tags: c, encryption, gnu, gmp

Has anyone successfully implemented the Cramer-Shoup encryption/decryption algorithm using the GNU GMP library? I suspect that I am subtly wrong with my implementation and based on what I write below, a simple affirmation of my suspicion would suffice - here is a wiki link of the general scheme: [Cramer-Shoup CryptoSystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%E2%80%93Shoup_cryptosystem)

I am trying to implement the Cramer-Shoup encryption scheme (and verification) in determining if anonymity should be revoked. It's with the key pair creation algorithm beginning on page 468 of [the TCG Software Stack (TSS) Specification Version 1.2 Level 1 Errata A](http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TSS_1_2_Errata_A-final.pdf) and the encryption part on page 446 and the verification on pp 471-472. I can do the math by hand and simple algebraic substitution gets me to where the verification checks pass (by hand). I use the GMP library and I have never had a problem with the other code I implemented using GMP functions for my application (commitments to attribute-based credentials). But now even trying several different solutions with the math library I keep getting wrong answers.

I have tried this on a Beagleboard with a TPM chip and Debian operating system. I spent this weekend at home making a non-TPM version to run on a VMware Ubuntu guest in a short program. I made sure any dynamic memory allocation was allocated before my equations and freed following the equations when no longer needed.

I also went through each step of calculation with a web-based calculator and ended up with the same wrong result. This part is why I suspect my code is the problem, not the GMP library.

I would post my code but it will break my character limit on this thread.

Thanks - I know my question is more philosophical in software development than otherwise but I do not want to confuse the community with detail.

Comment: Break down the code into the smallest compilable piece that exhibits the problem and others can run to reproduce and post that, along with the input, expected output, and actual output.  I.e. a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks! I will do so.

Answer (score 1):

I took another long look at the implementation. There is supposed to be a certain order of arguments and I had them switched in two places. Thanks for taking the time to view this problem and offer suggestions!

GMP working!